# Javascript check if a site url is accessible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to come up with the best jquery method to check to see if a site url is accessible.  All I need to do is confirm that the user can access the site.  However, with CORS i'm not quite sure of the best way to do this.  I've been trying this but running into issues.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: url,
    success: function(){
      callback(true);
    },
    error: function() {
      callback(false);
    }
  });
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://my-site.com. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: `success` not `succees`.

Comment: Thinking about this... receiving a CORS header error would indicate that the client can access the site. If the user could not resolve the URL, you wouldn’t receive a CORS error. If the URL was down, you wouldn’t get a CORS error.

Comment: @S.Walker that is also a valid point .. maybe there is not going to be an easy way to accomplish this.

Comment: @S.Walker You don't know that.  A good number of people have ISPs which automatically answer requests to invalid host names.  Or, captive portal pages on WiFi.  There isn't a way to tell cross-origin.

Answer (score 1):

Due to cross-origin restrictions, you won't be able to do this client-side.  You'll have to have some service running server-side.

Comment: The issue is that I'm looking to test the connectivity from the client's browsers - not the server to certain sites.

Comment: @AaronA You can't, due to cross-origin restrictions.  (Unless of course the site allows you to do this... but if they did, I assume you wouldn't have asked the question.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add crossDomain property with value true, also initialize support cors by true.

```
$.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: url,
    crossDomain: true,
    succees: function(){
      callback(true);
    },
    error: function() {
      callback(false);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use`

```
function UrlExists(url, cb){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:      url,
                dataType: 'text',
                type:     'GET',
                complete:  function(xhr){
                    if(typeof cb === 'function')
                       cb.apply(this, [xhr.status]);
                }
            });
        }

        UrlExists('-- Insert Url Here --', function(status) {
            if(status === 200) {
                -- Execute code if successful --
            } else if(status === 404) {
                -- Execute code if not successful --
            }else{
               -- Execute code if status doesn't match above --
            }
        });
```

Comment: This does not solve the cross-origin problem outlined in the question.